# Why if F - simple function: F.prototype!== F.__proto__ but Function.prototype === Function.__proto__?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, proto, function.prototype

Why if `F` - simple function:

```
F.prototype !== F.__proto__
```

but

```
Function.prototype === Function.__proto__
```

?

Comment: Function.prototype === Function.__proto__

Comment: Because `Function` is a special snowflake?

Comment: Why did you expect it to be otherwise? What else did you expect it to refer to?

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated, you should not use it any longer. Please use `Object.getPrototypeOf(…)` instead

Comment: [*Read the spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-constructor), it's defined that way: "*The value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot of the Function constructor is the intrinsic object [%FunctionPrototype%](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object)*".

Comment: *Why?* Because that's the way the language is designed, as documented in hundreds or thousands of articles, intros, tutorials, blog entries, and yes, questions right here on SO. There is hardly anything more basic than the difference between `Foo.prototype`, used as the prototype for objects created with `new Foo`, and `Foo.__proto__`, the prototype based on which `Foo` was created.

Comment: @werty, did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43963896/2545680) help?

Answer (score 1):

> `F.prototype !== F.__proto__`

Suppose you're designing an API for all functions. So you define that every function should have the method `call`. You create an object with such method:

```
var fproto = {call: ()=>{}};
```

Then for all functions to share this functionality, you have to add it to `.prototype` property of a Function constructor, [so that all instances of a Function inherit it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#prototype_and_Object.getPrototypeOf). So you do the following:

```
Function.prototype = fproto.
```

Now, when you create a function `F`, it will have have its `.__proto__` set to `fproto`:

```
const F = new Function();
F.call(); // works because of lookup in prototype chain through `__proto__` property
F.__proto__ === Function.prototype; // true
```

Now you decide that all instances created using `F` constructor, should have a method `custom`, so you create an object `iproto` with the property and set it as a prototype for all instances of `F` using `prototype` property:

```
const iproto = {custom: ()=>{}};
F.prototype = iproto;

const myobj = new F();
myobj.custom(); // works
```

So now it should be clear that `F.__proto__` and `F.prototype` are not the same object. And this is essentially what happens under the hood when you declare a function:

```
const F = function() {};

// F.__proto__ is set to Function.prototype to inherit `call` and other methods
F.__proto__ === Function.prototype

// F.prototype is set to a new object `{constructor: F}` and so:
F.prototype !== Function.prototype
```

> `Function.prototype === Function.__proto__`

Is an exceptional case because `Function` constructor should have all methods available for function instances, and hence `Function.__proto__`, but all share these methods with function instances, hence `Function.prototype`.